# viewpager page not change on click

Tags: android, android-layout

When I click on gallery item, I want to change the view pager item but when I do below code nothing happens as per expectations.

I have read many stackoverflow ans and implemented based on that but no luck

View pager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/gallery"
 />
```

Gallery

```
 <Gallery
        android:layout_below="@id/top"
                android:id="@+id/gallery"
                android:spacing="20dp"
                         android:background="#000075"

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </Gallery>

newGalleryAdapter =new newGalleryAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrCatName,arrCatBool);
        gallery.setAdapter(newGalleryAdapter);
        gallery.setSelection(0);
```

pager adapter

```
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(arrCatId.size());

    for (int j = 0; j < arrCatId.size(); j++) {
        finalcontentpaths.add(arrCatId.get(j));
    }

    listProductItemAdapter= new MyPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, finalcontentpaths);

    pager.setAdapter(listProductItemAdapter);
    listProductItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

**gallery item click**

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                setPosition(position,save);     
                newGalleryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                gallery.setSelection(position);
                save = position;

                //int a=pager.getCurrentItem()+1;
                pager.setCurrentItem(position,false);
                pager.setCurrentItem(position,true);
                pager.setCurrentItem(position);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is your gallery?

Comment: why are you passing `position` to `pager.setCurrentItem()` ? the `position` variable in `onItemClick` method is the position of the clicked item in your gallery recyclerview

Comment: @Bhargav : I want to do like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be useful for you.

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
      pager.setCurrentItem(position);
      setPosition(position,save);
      newGalleryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      gallery.setSelection(position);
      save = position;
    }
});
```

Hope it would help you.